# Which polygon tile grids allow convex polygons to be formed from multiple tiles?

Tags: geometry

If I have a grid made of equilateral triangles, I can easily form larger convex polygons as a set of tiles in that grid. I believe this holds for some (but not all) tilings of non-equilateral triangles.

The same for quadrilaterals - it's obvious for squares, rectangles and parallelograms, but I believe it also holds for some other (but not all) tilings of quadrilaterals.

I'm pretty sure tiling a flat area purely with convex pentagons is impossible, so skip that case.

With hexagons, a tiled grid is possible, but the only way to make a convex polygon from those convex hexagonal tiles seems to be to use only one tile - no multi-tile convex polygons seem possible.

My speculation is that it's only possible to form a multi-tile convex polygon from convex polygon tiles if all those tiles have interior angles at all vertices of 90 degrees or less, at least for those vertices that are at a vertex or edge of that larger convex polygon.

Is that speculation correct? Is there a proof or disproof?

Comment: Just to add a clarification: the plane *can* be tiled with convex pentagons, in many ways. If one requires the pentagons to be congruent, there are [exactly 15 ways this can happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_tiling#Monohedral_convex_pentagonal_tilings).

Comment: @RavenclawPerfect - Interesting. Honestly, I think I had a bunch of unstated rules at the time, though I don't really remember. In particular, I think I wanted the larger polygons being formed to also form a regular tiling - think of the way that a tiling of equilateral triangles can be viewed as a tiling of regular hexagons where each hexagon is formed from six equilateral triangles. Anyway, basically a big problem was that I probably didn't really know what I meant. In any case, my speculation as stated was disproven - counterexamples in the top answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - I figured it out within a minute of posting. Should have thought longer before asking.

If two polygons are joined such that such that a vertex and edge are on the same point and line, there are two cases...

- If the sum of the two interior angles is greater than 180 degrees, this is a concavity. It's only valid as part of a larger convex polygon if that concavity is filled by more tiles.
- If the sum of the two interior angles is less than or equal to 180 degrees, there is no concavity. This vertex may be at the vertex or edge of a larger convex polygon formed from these tiles.

So the issue is the sum of the angles, not the interior angle at the vertex of one particular tile.

Comment: Ed Pegg's lovely photo shows that what you've just stated is part but not all of the answer (I don't know the full answer). The regular square and triangular tilings have the property that the union of any two adjacent tiles is convex. For the regular hexagonal tiling not only is that not true, but no union of multiple tiles is convex. Ed's answer shows that it's possible to be in between: no union of two adjacent tiles is convex, yet there is a convex union of tiles. So I think it remains an interesting question: which monohedral tilings by a convex tile admit a convex union?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for items like the Hirschhorn Medallion?

[image: Hirschhorn Medallion]

Comment: Very nice, but no. The idea started when I was reading a blog post about pathfinding in square grids, and I wondered how far I could generalise to different grids. I thought about an idea I had some time ago about defining cells for the pathfinding to work on where each cell was as large as possible while being convex (so any point within a cell could be reached from any other in one step - I also had a variant where any point could be reached from any other in two steps via a centre point).

Comment: The two pathfinding ideas are separate anyway. Tthe whole point of defining convex cells is that there are no pre-defined cells, and the whole point of the two-step non-convex cells is to cope with e.g. circular barriers - if everything is defined on a square/whatever grid these should be non-issues. Basically, I was just going off on a random tangent. maybe thinking about optimising pathfinding on a grid by combining cells. Though this certainly shows a case where larger convex cells are possible, but can't be found by growing incrementally larger convex cells.